# Building Java based Kaa actor gateway

Tags: java, kaa

I would like to build a kaa actor gateway using java SDK. The actuator should handle data from different endpoints (temperature sensor - humidity sensor - ...), and log their data to the kaa platform.
How can be this done what sachems I should define from Admin console and what are the API I should use from the generated SDK? I can't find any example for this in the kaa sandbox sample projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more details about kaa actor gateway [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/kaaproject/SZBmH8txSbU). Also, 
there is a [ticket](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-111) with detailed description to create actor gateway demo application. I hope that this information will be helpful.

Comment: Actually I am looking for example code to use, the post is not so helpful